# How to get path of module entry in another module using webpack?

Tags: webpack

Our application has multiple entry points (say A and B). What we need is to get the generated name of the entry point A and use it in module B. The name of entry point A must contain the hash. Is it possible to do it just by webpack configuration and some loader/plugin?

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to write own plugin that modifies the file in `after-emit` phase when it is possible to get filenames from the stats:

```js
const replace = require("replace-in-file");
const path = require('path');

function PlaceholderToAssetReplacerPlugin(options) {
  this.options = options;
}

PlaceholderToAssetReplacerPlugin.prototype.apply = function (compiler) {
  const self = this;

  compiler.plugin('after-emit', function (compilation, callback) {
    const stats = compilation.getStats().toJson({
      hash: false,
      publicPath: true,
      assets: true,
      chunks: false,
      modules: false,
      source: false,
      errorDetails: false,
      timings: false
    });

    const assetsByChunkName = stats.assetsByChunkName;
    replace({
      files: path.join(__dirname, self.options.path, assetsByChunkName[self.options.sourceChunkName]),
      replace: new RegExp(self.options.variable),
      with: `"${assetsByChunkName[self.options.destinationChunkName]}"`
    }, (err, changedFiles) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      callback();
    });
  });
};

module.exports = PlaceholderToAssetReplacerPlugin;
```

then use it like this:

```js
new PlaceholderToAssetReplacerPlugin({
  path: '../dist/static',
  sourceChunkName: 'embedApiLoader',
  destinationChunkName: 'embedApi',
  variable: '__EMBED_API_ASSET__'
})
```